# Maven Jspc plugin not working with java 8

Tags: java-8, maven-3

We are using maven-jspc-plugin with java 8 and it’s giving class compilation errors though we are giving source and target as 1.6 java version.
So it’s not working with 1.8 or 1.6 java versions.

Unknown target VM 1.6 ignored.
Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
Arrays cannot be resolved
The type java.util.Comparator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jspc-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>compile-jsp</id>
<goals>
<goal>jspc</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<jasperClassDebugInfo>false</jasperClassDebugInfo>
<compilerSourceVM>1.6</compilerSourceVM>
<compilerTargetVM>1.6</compilerTargetVM>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Though old question, You have to use jdk 1.6 or 1.7. Take a look here. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2334194